# array_agg from two different tables without join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to take inputs as array from two different tables which are not related.

#### Sample Data

CITY1 TABLE

| NAME | TOT_POP |
| --- | --- |
| city1 | 10 |
| city2 | 20 |

FACILITIES TABLE

| NAME | Quota |
| --- | --- |
| f1 | 1 |
| f2 | 2 |
| f3 | 3 |
| f4 | 4 |

#### Close solution I found

```
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t1."TOT_POP") as City_Pop, ARRAY_AGG(t2."Quota") as Facility_Quota FROM 
(SELECT "TOT_POP", row_number() OVER (order by (SELECT 0)) FROM CITY1) as t1 right JOIN  
(select "Quota", row_number() OVER (order by (SELECT 0)) FROM FACILITIES) as t2 on t1.row_number = t2.row_number;
```

The output array contains null and joining on key is unnecessary in my case.

| City_Pop | Facility_Quota |
| --- | --- |
| {10,20,NULL,NULL} | {1,2,3,4} |

I want the following result, without using join if possible

| City_Pop | Facility_Quota |
| --- | --- |
| {10,20} | {1,2,3,4} |

Comment: Please provide sample data as well as desired results.

Comment: Thanks for returning. I actually work with geometries and use st_accum to aggregate geometry column in postgis. But this example should be enough. If not I can edit again.

Comment: `OVER (order by (SELECT 0))` can be simplified to `over ()`

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

You are over complicating things. Just use two scalar subqueries:

```
select (select array_agg(tot_pop) from city1) as city_pop,
       (select array_agg(quota) from facilities) as facility_quot;
```

or slightly faster:

```
select (array(select tot_pop from city1)) as city_pop,
       (array(select quota from facilities)) as facility_quot;
```

Comment: A fundamental approach was what I need

I was aggregating at the top level. I wanted to do as you suggest but I was not sure how. Thanks again @a_horse_with_no_name